# How to fix hh:mm format

Tags: excel, vba, datetime

I have an Excel file imported from a specific information system. I have been working with its automation through VBA code. However i encountered a problem while dealing with hh:mm cells. I can't sum them up, I tried formatting them to hh:mm, I also tried to format my output cell as [HH]:MM, none of it seems to work.

I guess the problem is with how the cells are formatted, they are in Times New Roman and seem a bit off.
I need a vba code to select a certain range and copy the ancien value and paste them again, but with the normal default Excel formatting.

[image]

Comment: Are they stored as `Text` by any chance? If you click formatting - General do they display an Excel date value or do they show as `00:00`?

Comment: No they are not, I changed the cell formats into hh:mm. I cleared the format using this
`Range(Cells(2, 5), Cells(LastRow, 13)).ClearFormats
Range(Cells(2, 5), Cells(LastRow, 13)).NumberFormat = "hh:mm"`
But the problem persists.

Comment: Try this `[h]:mm` This should be the format of the cell which has the sum formula.

Comment: Tried it, it just doesnt work, it still gives me 00:00

Comment: even though i cleared the formatting, the value are still left-centered, whilst when I type a normal hh:mm value into another cell it's right-centered by default. I just think that that's the problem.

Comment: It will if the cells have Valid time

Comment: Format the cells as General and then press F2 and then Enter and now check

Comment: That worked with the formatting! but how can I automate this process, I cant do this manually to thousands of cells..

Comment: One moment, Posting an answer.

Comment: What does a formula like `{=SUM(TIMEVALUE(A1:D6))}` on your raw data give you? Change your range obviously. With your output cell formatted as `[hh]:mm`

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thank you so much I automated the process you talked of using the piece of code bellow and it worked perfectly.
`
Sub ApplyF2()
    Selection.Value = Selection.FormulaR1C1
End Sub
`

Comment: An easier solution is just to put the number 1 in a blank cell, then copy it and use paste special -> Multiply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to custom format the cell where you are summing to `[h]:mm`

This may not work if the time is not correct in the source cells or are formatted as Text. You can manually format the cells as `General` and then press <kbd>F2</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to check if it works.

Before you automate this, you need to understand what we are doing.

1. Changing the format
2. Changing the `Formula` of the cell and not the `Value`. In this case, however both are the same.

> how can I automate this process, I cant do this manually to thousands of cells.. – Yassine Lachgar 2 mins ago

Try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long
    Dim rng As Range, aCell As Range

    '~~> Set this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet1

    With ws
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            '~~> Find Last row and last column
            lastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row

            lastCol = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Column

            '~~> Identify your range
            Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastRow, lastCol))

            '~~> Set the format. Be careful with this
            '~~> This will overwrite existing formats
            rng.NumberFormat = "General"

            '~~> Perform F2 + Enter via code
            For Each aCell In rng
                aCell.Formula = aCell.Value
            Next aCell
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```